# Why would an application trace show a lot of time spent allocating memory, but report no memory allocated?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I am investigating a ~6 second freeze in C# .net framework application on Windows 10. I am able to repro the freeze and have taken profiler traces using dotTrace and PerfView. What I see is that the freeze is associated with high CPU on a number of threads and that those threads are spending their time in clr!JIT_New and clr!JIT_NewArr1. The freeze is triggered by generating a lot of user input so this makes sense to me. However, the traces also report no GC.AllocationTick events during the freeze so it appears no actual allocation is taking place.

If the freeze was caused by new-ing up too many objects, I would expect a high allocation rate. Instead I am seeing the allocation rate drop to zero during the freeze. It is not doing a blocking GC either, according to the traces. There are no GC wait events during the freeze.

So the main question is: **What could cause the application to spend the majority of it's time allocating memory, but result in no memory being allocated?**

Some background: We are using .Net Framework V4.8. There are a number of processes making up the app, one of which has high CPU and starves the others. This process is always in GC.SustainedLowlatency mode. Some of the others go into this mode when they receive some user input, reverting to Interactive after 5 seconds.

In addition to threads being stuck in clr!JIT_New / JIT_NewArr1, one thread is stuck in GC.GetTotalMemory(false).

The issue appears to be affected by attaching a debugger. Capturing a dump with WinDbg seems to clear the freeze momentarily, so I don't have a detailed dump.

It's hard to be certain with only sampled stack traces, but it appears when a thread enters JIT_New or GetTotalMemory, it then does not leave until the freeze is over, at which point various network timeout exceptions occur and there is a flurry of activity.

The Events report in PerfView shows no garbage collection during the freeze. There is a GC.Start and GC.Stop pair just before the freeze, and then none until it is over. All other GC events also go silent during this time, including AllocationTick.

Comment: It's not yet an answer so just a comment - `JIT_New` may trigger GC so I'd assume you somehow don't get GC-related events. You may watch my [.NET GC Internals - 07. Allocations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZWG-5P8O6k&list=PLpUkQYy-K8Y-wYcDgDXKhfs6OT8fFQtVm&index=7) for details about `JIT_New` and GC relation.

Comment: Thank you that was useful to understand the exact job of JIT_New helper. For anyone stumbling upon this in the future, the most relevant section of the video starts [at ~57:29](https://youtu.be/oZWG-5P8O6k?list=PLpUkQYy-K8Y-wYcDgDXKhfs6OT8fFQtVm&t=3449) however the whole video gives a good background to what is going on during allocation

Comment: Now the question is whether GC, and of what type, is indeed triggered during such a freeze. If you can replicate, I'd start with "GCStats" report, without CPU sampling.

Comment: I can see in the Events report there is no GC triggered during freeze. Is there an advantage to taking a profile with 'CPU Samples' disabled?

I will try next:  1)Newer .net version  2) Lengthen the delay before reverting from SustainedLowLatency and see if freeze extends.  3) If it's useful I can post a link to a PerfView trace.